# Modals usage can/could

Tags: modal-verbs, present-perfect, can-could

We were checking some exercises and I wanted to know what's the correct modal to use:

> Gemma is away in Australia all summer. You ___ (can / see) her yesterday!

The answer is *can't have seen*, which is I selected. However, some of my classmates were saying that *couldn't have seen* is also an option. Is this valid too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are valid, with only very slightly differences in meaning (for most purposes they are all but identical). In fact, I would find *couldn't have seen* more appropriate, especially since the event in question clearly occurred yesterday.

This is an example of a conditional perfect tense (e.g. *would have been*) with a modal verb (*can*/*could*) replacing the standard *would*.

Interestingly, the structure "could have [past participle]" appears to be fairly rare when discussing these kinds of modal constructions. For example, this [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/can-could-and-could-have) page and this [SpeakSpeak](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/modal-verbs/past-probability-must-have-cant-have-couldnt-have) page both discuss the *could have* formation but not the *can have* formation (at least, not in its positive sense; *can't have* is discussed). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Can_and_could) mentions that *can have been* is a "rarer alternative" to *could have been*, but that section is listed without source, so take from that what you will.

Beyond the grammar, *couldn't* in this context appears to be more common in my experience, and is evidenced in [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can%27t+have+seen%2Ccouldn%27t+have+seen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20not%20have%20seen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20have%20seen%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Yes, I thought the same. Despite having *yesterday* as a time expression, the natural way is to use *couldn't have seen*, but I discarded this option since at the beginning we have *Gemma is away* and not *Gemma was away.* The book points for *can't have seen*, but if two options were available, why wouldn't they put them as well?

Comment: @Nonnal: Good answer, but my ear prefers the directness of "can't." Ale also makes a good point in the comment above. One aside: Skype has rendered this sample sentence obsolete.

Comment: @Ale Since Gemma is away "all summer," this is less about the present tense and more about a statement of her ongoing absence. "Gemma was away all summer" implies that she no longer is away. No clue why they would put two correct answers as options, but *could have seen* is clearly preferable to my eye.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Fair enough. I wouldn't be surprised if the can't-vs-couldn't distinction has regional variance as a factor. I've edited the post and added some references to support my position that *couldn't* is more common and preferable in the general use case, but I wouldn't be surprised to discover that *can have seen* is more common in certain geographies.

Comment: @Nonnal Agreed, and thank you for the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a grammar versus usage issue here.

Strictly speaking, your book is correct and your classmates are wrong. The sentence is a past probability in which the construction is:

modal verb + have + past participle = *can't have seen*

The justification is that *seen* marks the sentence for the past, so there is no need to mark the modal as well.

But... *couldn't have seen* sounds natural enough to me, and if comments below Nonnal's post are any guide it sounds natural to others too. My hunch is that using *couldn't* instead of *can't* marks for irrealis, often in a conditional sentence such as "If she is in Australia, you couldn't have seen her yesterday", so a lot of people subconsciously see this a a conditional sentence because not seeing her is true only if her being in Australia is true.